# XeLaTeX and the characters "éèàç"

Tags: xetex, input-encodings

Using accented characters (`éèçà`...) I get a space in my output rather than the correct symbol in all of my tests. I am using XeLaTeX: what is wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt, plain]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} %For loading graphic files
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage [Glenn]{fncychap}%chapitre format
\usepackage{shapepar} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage[cc]{titlepic}%page de garde
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}%chapitre format
\usepackage{titletoc}% 
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Будет ли ответ по русски полезный для Вас? (In the other words: French is probably as exotic as Russian for most of the users).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with some content required to reproduce the issue and `\end{document}`. Also, you should reduce your preamble to just those packages needed to produce the problem. This may all seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: To the anonymous down voters: unless the meaning of the post is itself nonsensical (or obscene, obnoxious etc.), I think down voting was uncalled for. This is a new user and new users deserve a chance to improve their first question without being penalised for their efforts. There are worse questions, in my view. This one clearly makes some effort to provide some code and that puts it ahead of many others. Moreover, the *second* down vote is even more *clearly* uncalled for. Dyw Saesneg ddim yn iaith yr holl byd! That said, I have no clue what is being asked as I don't speak French.

Comment: @cfr I've downvoted for using French, but answered. I hope that now my behaviour is balanced. :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke If it weren't a first post, I'd agree. But really it was the fact that *two* people down voted. -1 surely sends a clear enough message for a first (non-spam, non-offensive etc.) post? And I guess I feel that life is somewhat unfair since English so dominates... Is there a similar site somebody could ask if s/he could not manage to do so in English?

Comment: @cfr -- Yes: [fr.comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fr.comp.text.tex) (<-- this links to the Google Groups interface).

Comment: I have translated (freely) to both deal with the language issue and to make the question fit better for the site. The MWE could in principle be shortened, but I will leave that for others!

Answer (score 2):

You have probably improper encodig. After switching to UTF-8 all characters in problem are visible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt, plain]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} %For loading graphic files
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage [Glenn]{fncychap}%chapitre format
\usepackage{shapepar} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage[cc]{titlepic}%page de garde
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}%chapitre format
\usepackage{titletoc}% 
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
Encoding changed to UTF-8

j'ai des espace à la place des lettres (éèçà...) j'ai tout testé ça marche pas PS: j'utilise xelatex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd be more inclined to upvote this answer if it did not preserve the redundancies of the preamble in the OP.

Comment: @jon Yes: the preamble is a nightmare. But let the new user have got his file as untouched, as possible.

Comment: I understand the inclination, but I'd be inclined to at least suggest that one should not load packages multiple times.